# Error while creating record in laravel - mongo Application

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-8

I am using a package for mongodb in laravel :  `"jenssegers/mongodb": "^3.8",`
migrations are working fine, but when I try to create a record using controller, its throwing error

```
InvalidArgumentException
Database connection [mongoproject] not configured.
```

my database.php

```
        'mongodb' => [
            'driver'   => 'mongodb',
            'host'     => env('MONGO_DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port'     => env('MONGO_DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('MONGO_DB_DATABASE'),
            'username' => env('MONGO_DB_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MONGO_DB_PASSWORD'),
            'charset'   => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix'    => '',
            'strict'    => false,
        ],
```

my .env

```
DB_CONNECTION=mongodb
MONGO_DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
MONGO_DB_PORT=27017
MONGO_DB_DATABASE=mongoproject
MONGO_DB_USERNAME=
MONGO_DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: have you created a database named mongoproject in your db server?

Comment: Yes, Actually the problem was with Model code

class Animal extends Eloquent
{
    //protected $connection = 'mongoproject';
    protected $collection = 'animals';
    
    protected $fillable = [
        'species', 'color','leg'
    ];
}

Comment: I have to comment this line protected $connection = 'mongoproject'

Comment: now its working fine